# How validate a cell in QTableWidget?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I work eith `pyqt4` in `python3.4` I want to validate if the text in the cell is a float number when it is introduced. How I do that?

Comment: Adding a validator can force the user to enter a number: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdoublevalidator.html If the input is not a number, it won't accept the input into the cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options.

You can create a `QItemDelegate` and override the `createEditor`, `setEditorData` and `setModelData` to control the widget they're presented with to edit the data.  You can create a `QLineEdit` with a validator if you'd like, but if they can only enter a number, you should probably just use a `QSpinBox` or `QDoubleSpinBox`, which only allow integers and floats.  Alternatively, you could let them enter whatever they want and then in the `setModelData` function just ignore any entered values that aren't valid numbers.

```
class MyDelegate(QtGui.QItemDelegate):

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        return QtGui.QSpinBox(parent)


delegate = MyDelegate()
table.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```

Or, a slightly easier solution if the items in your table already have numbers, just assign an integer or float to the `EditData` role for the item.  `Qt` will notice the class type and automatically construct a `QSpinBox` or `QDoubleSpinBox` for you.

```
item = QTableWidgetItem()
item.setData(QtCore.Qt.EditRole, 5)
```

Comment: I try use `QItemDelegate` and works **but** I need a float and that only allows me work whit integer

Comment: Use a `QDoubleSpinBox` if you want to work with floats

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you tell me where I can find documentation about QItemDelegate? It is that I do not like writing code you do not understand

Comment: Just google "pyqt qitemdelegate" -- http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qitemdelegate.html

Comment: For the non-delegate path: If we set the EditRole to int, how are we supposed to then set the text of the item as displayed? Using `item.setText(str(value))` makes the item accept anything when edited and not display any special widget.