# How to tell when a QTableWidgetItem is being modified

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I'm writing an app in Python with the *PySide* library. I have a `QTableWidget` that gets updated about every second. The thing is, I want to be able to change the data manually, and I thought that if I could find out whether or not the user is changing the data in the cell, then I could just prevent the program from updating this cell. Otherwise I get "kicked out" of the cell at each update.

- Is this a good idea? Should I try something else and why?
- How can I achieve my goal?

Many thanks

---

**EDIT :**

I know there exists an `itemChanged` signal, but what I'd really like to know is if there is a way to tell *when the user is writing a new value in the cell*, in order not to kick them out while editing.

Comment: Sounds like for the same cell, you have two possible sources to change it, every second updated by program, at the same time, you allow user changing it. The end result is sometimes, one meant to step on each other's toe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Qt Document:

**void QTableWidget::itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem * item)

This signal is emitted whenever the data of item has changed.**

Hope this will help you.

Edit:

QTableWidget uses a default itemdelegate(QItemDelegate instance) which has createEditor method and closeEditor signal.

You can reimplement createEditor which means edit starts, and connect the signal closeEditor which means the edit ends.

This may be the correct way.

Comment: I know about this, but what about when the item _is being changed_ ?

Comment: To give a simple way, you can connect the signal "cellDoubleClicked" which means user has entered edit mode and set a flag such as "isEditing" to be True. Also, you need to implement "mousePressEvnet" and "focusOutEvent" in your tablewidgetclass to set "isEditing" to be False which means user has finished editing.Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you would handle this situation with the use of [`QItemDelegates`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qitemdelegate.html), which allow you to control what cells are editable by the user, what types of controls they are given to edit the cells, and you can catch the data they input and validate or manipulate it before saving it to the model.

`QItemDelegates` only control edits being made using the view interface.  If the table is being updated programmatically, the changes won't be sent to the `QItemDelegate`.

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37623147/1547004) of a `QItemDelegate` for a `QTableWidget`